# How to deal FineUI Grid control data misplacement?

Tags: asp.net, grid

Recently I downloaded FineUI Control to build Website. It’s easy to use and build website. Now I meet a problem When I use FIneUI Grid control. Data misplacement occurred when I bind data at the Grid1_RowDataBound(). Result is there is no data at the first line and the first line’s data jumps to second line.
Grid1_RowDataBound() code:

```
protected void Grid1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        FineUI.CheckBoxField field1 = (FineUI.CheckBoxField)Grid1.FindColumn("CheckBoxField1");
        FineUI.LinkButtonField link1 = (FineUI.LinkButtonField)Grid1.FindColumn("linkTY");
        FineUI.LinkButtonField link2 = (FineUI.LinkButtonField)Grid1.FindColumn("linkBTY");

        object o = Grid1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataKeys[1].ToString();
        object d = Grid1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataKeys[3].ToString();
        bool flag1 = getGYSApply(o);
        link1.Text = d.ToString();
        Alert.Show(o + "-" + d);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Bug. When you use RowDataBound(), the data of each line has been bound,  at this point it will have no use at all if you change the attributes of the column. The way to solve this problem is changing the event from RowDataBound() to PreRowDataBound().